# Nicely format the output and send it through email in HTML format

Tags: html, bash, unix, sh

So i have a multiple function (6 to be exact) that is being called after my `for` loop which is redirected to a file.

```
function tpcaA (){

if [[ $(egrep 'offline|degraded' ${tmp}/portstat.tpcaA) ]]; then
echo -e "TPCaA is: Degraded"
else
echo -e "PTCaA is: All Online"
fi

}
exec 1>${tmp}/portout
then for loop here
tpcaA  **<-- called my function here**
```

and the file (**portout**) looks like this.

```
    TPC Port Status

 TPCa-A is: Degraded
 TPCb-B is: Degraded
 TPCd-D is: Degraded
 STPa-A is: Degraded
 STPb-B is: Degraded
 STPc-C is: Degraded
 STPd-D is: Degraded
```

I know html a bit and i can play it around.

Question is;

- How can i nicely format the output and send it through email. Say if it's `Degraded`, it should be color red and if it's `all online` is should be green?
- How can i make it center align?
- Is it also possible to put `border` to it?
- How can i attach another file to my email?

I'm using this part below to send the email.

```
emailBody="From: <bbb@tpc.com>
Subject: Report1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"
<html>
<body>



</body>
</html>
"
echo "$emailBody" | sendmail aaa@tpc.com
```

Comment: Your questions seem all very basic HTML questions. You can answer them from almost any HTML tutorial

Comment: @mplungjan, Thank you. I know HTML but i need a little help on how to add that in the shell script. Right now it is sending a plain text to my outlook email. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Something like this`<html>
<style>
div>span {white-space: pre;}
.Degraded { color:red }
.Online { color: green }
<body>
<div>
tpcaA 
</div>
</body>
</html>` where you echo  `"<span class=Degraded>TPCaA is: Degraded</span><br/>"` in the function